# How do I include a variable in the condition of a while loop if the variable is changed inside said loop in c#

Tags: c#, variables

I'm trying to have the user input a number from 1 to 5 and I want to loop back and have the user input another number if it isn't within those bounds. Here is the code:

```
int charNum = 0;

while(!((charNum > 0) && (charNum < 6)) ) {

    int charNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
}
```

The above gives one error which says:

"A local or parameter named 'charNum' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

I've tried incorporating multiple variables but seem to encounter the same problem with changing variables inside a loop.

Is there a way to get around this or am I missing an easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple mistake. You're attempting to re-declare the charNum variable inside the loop. Simply remove the int and it becomes an assignment instead of a declaration.

Answer (score 4):

You should ***never*** use `Convert` style methods and ***always*** use the `TryParse` style methods for *user input*... Users with *dirty little fingers* will type the wrong thing...

Here is an example which does all the above and your range check in the one line with a user message on failure

```
int charNum = 0;

while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out charNum ) || charNum < 0 || charNum >= 6) 
  Console.WriteLine("You had one job, now enter the number correctly");
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, it was something I had decided to let my future self figure out

Comment: Just to add a little extra caution, I've found it much safer to use `double.TryParse` and then cast to an int if needed. `int.TryParse` will fail if the user includes a decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to create another variable within your loop with the exact same name as the variable outside of the loop. You just need to *assign* a value to the variable, not *declare* it.

```
int charNum = 0;

while(!((charNum > 0) && (charNum < 6)) ) {

    charNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
}
```

**EDIT**

I would also look at the post [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820953/13079914), as it gives great insight into what not to do in this situation.